# The page load is not working in asxp.vb

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have two things happen in this script.First I can add and also I can do update.However, I am not sure what is wrong with codes when I want to add new, I goes straight to catch, n when I want to update, it didn't work either.
Can someone help me with this. I am kind of new for .net

Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Partial Class Setup_setup_callCenterAdd

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private _strServerUrl As String = ""
Private _intLoginUserID As Integer = 0
Private _intUserID As Integer = 0
Private _objCallCenterDS As DataSet
Private _objCallCentertAdapt As MySqlDataAdapter
Private _objSecurity As New StringBusinessObject.Web.businessSecurityClass()
Private _objCommonData As New clsCommonData()
Private _strTarget As String = ""
```

## Region "Page Event"

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    '_objCallCenterDS = _objCommonData.fnLoadCallCenterAdd(_objCallCentertAdapt)
    Dim strProjectCode, strReport, strDescription, strSite, strStatus, strCause As String
    '    _objCallCenterDS = _objCommonData.fnLoadCallCenterDisplay(_intUserID, _objCallCentertAdapt)
    Try



        '_intLoginUserID = CInt(Session("sUserID").ToString())
        strProjectCode = ""
        strReport = ""
        strDescription = ""
        strSite = ""
        strStatus = ""
        strCause = ""

        _intUserID = CInt(Request("UserIDClicked").ToString())
        _strServerUrl = "http://" & System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
        _objCallCenterDS = _objCommonData.fnLoadCallCenterDisplay(_intUserID, _objCallCentertAdapt)
        ' If Request("UserIDClicked") <> Nothing Then

        If Not Page.IsPostBack = True Then


            If _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                strReport = ""
                strProjectCode = _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("project_code_id").ToString()
                strReport = strReport
                strDescription = _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("description").ToString()
                strSite = _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("site").ToString()
                strStatus = _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("status").ToString()
                strCause = _objCallCenterDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("cause").ToString()

            End If


            Dim objDataTable As System.Data.DataTable = _objCommonData.fnLoadProjectCodeList(1)
            ddlProjectCode.DataSource = objDataTable
            ddlProjectCode.DataTextField = "project_code"
            ddlProjectCode.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlProjectCode.DataBind()

            ddlProjectCode.SelectedValue = strProjectCode
            strReport = strReport
            txtDescription.Text = strDescription
            txtSite.Text = strSite
            ddStatus.SelectedItem.Text = strStatus
            txtCause.Text = strCause


            '_objCallCenterDS = Nothing
            '_objCallCenterDS = _objCommonData.fnLoadCallCenterAdd(_objCallCentertAdapt)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

## End Region

## Region "Save into Table Project"

```
Private Function fnSaveIntoProject(ByVal objTargetDS As DataSet, ByVal objTargetAdapt As MySqlDataAdapter, _
                            ByVal strProjectCode As String, ByVal strReport As String, _
                            Byval strDescription As String, ByVal strSite As String, _
                            ByVal strStatus As String, ByVal strCause As String, _
                            ByRef strErrMessage As String) As Integer

    Dim intInsertResult As Integer = 0
    Dim intUpdateResult As Integer = 0
    Dim objNewRow As DataRow = objTargetDS.Tables(0).NewRow()
    Dim objExistedRow() As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim exError As New System.Exception
    'Dim UserID As String = Session("sUserID")


    Try
        objExistedRow = objTargetDS.Tables(0).Select("id = " & _intUserID.ToString())

        If objExistedRow.Length > 0 Then
            objExistedRow(0)("project_code_id") = ddlProjectCode.SelectedValue
            objExistedRow(0)("description") = txtDescription.Text.Trim()
            objExistedRow(0)("site") = txtSite.Text.Trim()
            objExistedRow(0)("status") = ddStatus.Text.Trim()
            objExistedRow(0)("cause") = txtCause.Text.Trim()

            intUpdateResult = StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnSaveAndUpdateDataBase(objTargetDS, _
                                                                                                        objTargetAdapt)

            If intUpdateResult = -1 Then
                exError = StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.pGetLastErrorExceptionObject
                strErrMessage = exError.Message.Trim()
            ElseIf intUpdateResult = -2 Then
                strErrMessage = "Same Project existed in database."
            End If
        Else

            strReport = ""
            objNewRow("project_code_id") = strProjectCode
            objNewRow("report_number") = strReport
            objNewRow("description") = strDescription
            objNewRow("site") = strSite
            objNewRow("status") = strStatus
            objNewRow("cause") = strCause
            objNewRow("last_modified_by") = Session("sUserID")
            objNewRow("datetimestamp") = System.DateTime.Now


            objTargetDS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(objNewRow)
            intInsertResult = StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnSaveAndUpdateDataBase(objTargetDS, _
                                                                                                     objTargetAdapt)

            '  End If
            Dim strYear As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")
            Dim strMonth As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
            Dim intLastInsertID As Nullable(Of Integer) = _objCommonData.fnGetLastInsertUserID()

            Dim strReportNumber As String = ddlProjectCode.SelectedItem.Text & "-" & strYear & "/" & strMonth & "/" & intLastInsertID.ToString()
            objNewRow("Report_number") = strReportNumber

            intInsertResult = StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnSaveAndUpdateDataBase(objTargetDS, _
                                                                                         objTargetAdapt)

            If intInsertResult = -1 Then
                exError = StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.pGetLastErrorExceptionObject
                strErrMessage = exError.Message.Trim()
            ElseIf intInsertResult = -2 Then
                strErrMessage = "Same Project existed in database."
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        strErrMessage = ex.Message.Trim()
    End Try

    'Return intInsertResult

End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "buttonRegister"

```
Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

    Dim strProjectCode, strReport, strDescription, strSite, strStatus, strCause As String
    Dim strPopUpScript, strErrMessage As String
    Dim intSaveProject, intLastInsertID As Integer

    strErrMessage = ""

    Try

        If ddlProjectCode.SelectedValue = "" Then
            strProjectCode = "0"
        ElseIf ddlProjectCode.SelectedValue = "0" Then
            strProjectCode = "0"
        Else
            strProjectCode = ddlProjectCode.SelectedValue
        End If


        'strReport = ddlProjectCode.DataTextField
        strDescription = txtDescription.Text.Trim()
        strSite = txtSite.Text.Trim()
        strStatus = ddStatus.Text.Trim()
        strCause = txtCause.Text.Trim()



        _strTarget = Page.ResolveClientUrl("setup_callCenter.aspx")
        strPopUpScript = "<script type=""text/javascript"">"
        strPopUpScript = strPopUpScript + "window.location.replace('" & _strTarget & "');"
        strPopUpScript = strPopUpScript + "</script>"

        intSaveProject = fnSaveIntoProject(_objCallCenterDS, _objCallCentertAdapt, strProjectCode, strReport, strDescription, strSite, strStatus, strCause, strErrMessage)

        intLastInsertID = _objCommonData.fnGetLastInsertUserID()

        If intSaveProject = 1 Then
            StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, "Save & Update Successful.")
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "PopupScript", strPopUpScript)
        Else
            StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, "Save & Update Unsuccessful. " & strErrMessage)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

## End Region

End Class

Comment: What is the error message you are getting from the catch block? Which of these calls is throwing the error?